# Why is my httpd.conf setup routing to https?

Tags: linux, apache, http, https, httpd.conf

I have a number of domains, each one pointing to my server IP..

I've pinged each domain to check the DNS, That's fine, all domains are pointing to the correct server.

All my domains route through the httpd.conf correctly via HTTP, except one domain where for some reason the Http <Virtual: *:80> entry is forwarding to https: (https://preprod.testsite.org.uk) - For security, this isn't the real URL.

Why would this entry fail when the others are fine?

Is there some way of debugging or tracing through the request from the DNS through to the server, through to the httpd.conf?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/testsite/production"
    ServerName preprod.testsite.org.uk

    <Directory /var/www/html/testsite/production>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

DNS has nothing to do with HTTP to HTTPs redirection.
Test it using curl (-v option) and check if the server is sending a Location to the client telling him to connect over HTTPs.
If curl says there's no redirection to https, might be the application itself telling the client to connect over https OR, maybe, some entry in browser HSTS cache.